# MAUI program won't connect to URL address (connection to local IP works) in android and IOS

Tags: android, ios, maui

I have a local server and client connected using the eneter messaging "using Eneter.Messaging"

I have an android and windows clients that works fine in this configuration.

I am rewriting the client using MAUI (so i can connect also to IOS)
the communication is working fine when i am using the local IP of the server (<"tcp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:85/">)
when i am using URL address <"tcp://name.DNS.com:85/"> it only works in windows, IOS and android do not connect.
there no router forwarding or net issues since it is working on windows and in my old android (written in android studio)

Is there any permission I need to add?

```
   private static void OpenConnection()
{
#if UesNetwork
    try
    {
        if (!mySender.IsDuplexOutputChannelAttached)
        {
            // The output channel is not attached yet.  
            // So attach the output channel and be able to send
            // request messagas and receive response messages.
            IMessagingSystemFactory aMessaging = new TcpMessagingSystemFactory()
            {
                // Set to receive messages in the main UI thread.
                // Note: if this is not set then methods OnResponseReceived and
                //       OnConnectionClosed would not be called from main UI thread
                //       but from a listener thread.
                //OutputChannelThreading = new WinFormsDispatching(this)
            };
            //        IDuplexOutputChannel anOutputChannel = aMessaging.CreateDuplexOutputChannel("tcp://" + serverip + ":" + serverport + "/");
            IDuplexOutputChannel anOutputChannel;
            anOutputChannel = aMessaging.CreateDuplexOutputChannel("tcp://name.DDNS.com:85/");  //("tcp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:85/");
            mySender.AttachDuplexOutputChannel(anOutputChannel);

            //ConnectionStatusLabel.Text = "Client Connected";
        }
        else if (!mySender.AttachedDuplexOutputChannel.IsConnected)
        {
            // The output channel is attached but the client got disconnected.
            // So jut reopen the connection.
            mySender.AttachedDuplexOutputChannel.OpenConnection();
            // ConnectionStatusLabel.Text = "Client Connected";
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        //MessageBox.Show("can not Open Connection  ");
    }
#endif
}
```

Comment: do you get an error or exception?  What specifically is it doing (or not doing)?

Comment: no error it simply fail to connect "IsConnected false bool"

i get an exception ( catch) since i add "try"

Comment: if i remove the try i get  "System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'Sockets on this platform are invalid for use after a failed connection attempt.'"

Comment: Did you try to debug to check which line caused `System.PlatformNotSupportedException`? And can you make sure the tcp url is supported on the native android and ios?

Comment: Did you try to debug to check which line caused : yes the line is  "                mySender.AttachDuplexOutputChannel(anOutputChannel); " when going in there is no debug information (  getting into the eneter firmware)  ;     the tcp url is supported since i am using it in my old android program (written in android studio)

Comment: So you can try to used the native android code to achieve that for android. Did you check the api's(mySender.AttachDuplexOutputChannel) attribute?